# Can I have website that navigates to different pages but doesn't reload the head/footer?

Tags: navigation

Is it possible to have a website that doesn't reload the entire page when you click a link to a different page on the website?

I know of 2 ways in which this could be done but they both have problems...

Using PHP I could pull in the same header and footer files for each page but... The entire page is being reloaded and grabbing the same header and footer each time, this is what I'd like to avoid.

Using something like Ajax I could refresh the main content of the page BUT as I understand it, I'm not technically navigating to a different page. Meaning it would all be under the same URL.

Is there another alternative?

Comment: I can't see how option #1 is a problem.

Comment: Because the entire page is being reloaded unnecessarily, I'd prefer it to be more seemless where you don't notice anything change except the main content.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like a web app!

You can use Reactjs, Angular, Vuejs ... etc. to achieve something like that using your js knowledge, if you are not that comfortable with PHP.

Comment: Thanks, are you able to give me a pointer as to where to start? Is there a particular method or anything using React that I can google?